# Simple "SELECT" query taking too long

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, postgresql-10, pgadmin, query-performance

I'm trying to run a SELECT query on our PostgreSQL database using pgAdmin 3. It looks like this:

```
SELECT
    tstamp AS "time"
    dvalue AS "Weight"
  FROM tablename
  WHERE
    tstamp BETWEEN 'time1' AND 'time2' AND description = "exp_weight"
  ORDER BY 1
```

Our database tracks metrics for a lot more than just weight so we have about 30 million rows to parse in order to find all the `exp_weight` rows. When I run this, it takes about a minute and a half to aggregate all of the data. Any idea how I can speed this up?

#### Considerations

- I'm running PostgreSQL 10.
- I've improved performance by adding a multicolumn index on `tstamp`, `description`, and `dvalue` which brings the runtime down to ~30 seconds. Ideally, I'd like to get this to less than a second.
- I've optimized the query a bit

  ```
  SELECT
      tstamp AS "time"
      dvalue AS "Weight"   
  FROM tablename   
  WHERE
      description = "exp_weight" AND tstamp BETWEEN 'time1' AND 'time2'   
  ORDER BY tstamp
  ```

The output to `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` is

```
Index Only Scan using tablename_description_tstamp_dvalue_idx on tablename (cost=0.56..76427.86 rows=1536760 width=16) (actual time=1.002..435.999 rows=1566102 loops=1)"
  Index Cond: ((description = 'exp_weight'::text) AND (tstamp >= '2019-03-17 16:21:57.305-05'::timestamp with time zone) AND (tstamp <= '2019-09-16 16:21:57.305-05'::timestamp with time zone))
  Heap Fetches: 0
  Buffers: shared hit=193 read=11212
  I/O Timings: read=150.105
Planning time: 0.132 ms
Execution time: 474.418 ms
```

But when I actually run the query it takes 30 seconds.

I've changed some parameters in the config file to allow higher `shared_buffers` and CPU usage

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the table? Particularly covering description and tstamp?

Comment: What part (amount or percent) of table records does this query selects? What part will be selected while using these conditions separately? And show full table's DDL, including indices.

Comment: Most important, show `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 0):

Sending 1,566,102 rows from the database to your client (possibly over a network) takes time, and then your client needs to parse them and figure out how to render them.

If it is much faster when you take the client out of the picture, then you now know where the bottleneck is.

Comment: By client, do you mean the pgAdmin3 front end?

Comment: Yes.  And pgAdmin3 is known to be slow in such situations.  But anything can be slow if you cram enough stuff into it.